# sql print returns strange result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql code:

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR
SET @result = 'FN'
print(@result)
```

It returns `F` to console.
why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a `VARCHAR`, you have to specify it's length. If you don't it defaults to 1.

Use:

```
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(2)
SET @result = 'FN'
print(@result)
```

Comment: I need 5 minutes to do this)

Comment: http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/07/22/0005/3037/338909/09/75a1940a4e.jpg